# Getting a string value that is between two characters

Tags: string, sql-server-2008, charindex

I need to get the value that is between !03 and !03.

Example:

```
JDC!0320151104!03OUT
```

I should get following string in return: 20151104

NOTE: The string isn't always 22 characters long, but I am only concerned with the value that is between !03 and !03.

This is what I have so far.  I couldn't make any progress further than this:

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(
RegStatsID, 
CHARINDEX('!', RegStatsID) + 3, 
CHARINDEX('!', REVERSE(RegStatsID))
)
 From TableX
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great that you found a solution!

This might be better:

By replacing the "!03" with XML-tags you can easily pick the second "node". Your string will be transformed into `<x>JDC</x><x>20151104</x><x>OUT</x>`:

```
DECLARE @test VARCHAR(100)='JDC!0320151104!03OUT';

SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@test,'!03','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML).value('/x[2]','datetime')
```

One advantage was to get the value between the two "!03" typed. In this case you get a "real" datetime back without any further casts. If the value there is not a datetime (or date) in all cases, you just use `nvarchar(max)` as type.

Another advantage was: If you - why ever - need the other values later, you just have them with `.value('/x[1 or 3]'...)`

Comment: Wow this is helpful.  I am going to try using this trick nexttime I am dealing with an issue like this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it right by doing following:

```
SELECT 
 SUBSTRING(
    RegStatsID, 
    CHARINDEX('!', RegStatsID) + 3, 
    len(RegStatsID) - CHARINDEX('!', RegStatsID ) - 2 -  CHARINDEX('!', Reverse(RegStatsID))
)
```